# How to GROUP BY on multiple DISTINCT columns? ( Google Big Query )

Tags: sql, distinct

1. The following code GROUPs by date, and counts DISTINCT "a" values.

```
    SELECT Date,
           COUNT(DISTINCT(a)),
    FROM process
    GROUP BY date
```

2. The following code shows the number of DISTINCT values in "a" and "b" columns:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a, b
          FROM process)
```

TRIED:
If I write this:

```
SELECT Date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(a, b)),
FROM process
GROUP BY date
```

I get

> ERROR: Aggregate functions with DISTINCT cannot be used with arguments
> of type STRUCT

QEUSTION: I need to count distinct values from "a" and "b" columns.
How do I combine 1 and 2 codes?

Columns and Values explained:
date: TIMESTAMP (DATE WAS EXTRACTED)
a = INT
b = STRING

Desired outcome table:
date (grouped) : 13.09.2002
distinct(count): 232

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) A [mcve].

Comment: What is the type of a and b columns? Create an expression for example `concat (a, '#@$', b)`  and count distinct  expressions.

Comment: I just have eddited my question and explained tables, values and desired outcome

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You have accepted a product specific answer, and it would be nice to let others know it isn't a universal solution.)

Comment: You are right sure. I am using it for Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to get distinct a, b combinations then this one could help:

```
SELECT
       Date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT(CONCAT(a,'_',b))) distinct_a_b
  FROM process
 GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Thank you I believe it worked!

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. I.e. simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a,'_',b)) distinct_a_b`, to make code clearer.